# Find and return column with max value from a list of vectors

Tags: r, function, apply, lapply, dcast

I'm trying to calculate favorite brand per productcategory per customer.

**1. Start and what I want to achieve**

I start with a dataframe (mydata) with purchase orders, build up like this:

| customer | ordernumber | productcategory | brand | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123456 | H11_plumbing | Nitrofill | 6 |
| ABC | 123457 | H11_plumbing | Antileak | 2 |
| DEF | 123458 | H11_plumbing | Nitrofill | 1 |
| DEF | 123459 | H11_plumbing | Antileak | 5 |
| ABC | 123460 | H12_electric | Shock | 10 |
| ABC | 123461 | H12_electric | Lightning | 5 |
| DEF | 123462 | H12_electric | Shock | 4 |
| DEF | 123463 | H12_electric | Lightning | 8 |

What I want to achieve is list per customer the favorite brand per productcategory.

| customer | H11_plumbing_favorite_brand | H12_electric_favorite_brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Nitrofill | Shock |
| DEF | Antileak | Lightning |

For customer ABC Nitrofill (amount = 6) and Shock (amount = 10) are favorites

**2. What I am doing now**

What I now did was create a list of vectors for each productcategory and change the shape from long to wide using lapply to use data.table::dcast

df_list <- split(mydata, as.factor(mydata$productcategory)) # create list of vectors

```
library(data.table)
df_list_2 <- lapply(df_list,function(x) x <- data.table::dcast(setDT(x), customer ~ brand, sum, value.var = c("amount"))) # change shape from long to wide
```

**3. Where I get stuck is finding and returning the column with the favorite brand**

This is where I get stuck. I have been able to do this for a data.frame (vector) rather than a list of vectors by using this code:

```
mydata_t <- mydata[mydata$productcategory=="H12_electric",]
mydata_overview<- data.table::dcast(setDT(mydata_t), customer ~ brand, sum, value.var = c("amount"))
rm(mydata_t)
mydata_overview$favorite_brand <- apply(mydata_overview[,-c(1)],1,function(x) which(x==max(x)))
```

However, if I try to use this code on the list of vectors (`df_list`) then it doesn't work.

```
df_list_3 <- lapply(df_list,function(x) x$favorite_brand<- apply(x[,-c(1)],1,function(y) which(y==max(y))))
rm(df_list_t)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach. Create a `favorite` column that includes the `brand` where you have the `max`imum `amount` (for each `customer` and `productcategory` combination). Then, use `dcast` to put into wide form, using the new `favorite` category as your value.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, .(favorite = brand[which.max(amount)]), by = .(customer, productcategory)][
  , dcast(.SD, 
          customer ~ productcategory, 
          value.var = "favorite")
]
```

**Output**

```
   customer H11_plumbing H12_electric
1:      ABC    Nitrofill        Shock
2:      DEF     Antileak    Lightning
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(customer = c("ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "ABC", 
"ABC", "DEF", "DEF"), ordernumber = 123456:123463, productcategory = c("H11_plumbing", 
"H11_plumbing", "H11_plumbing", "H11_plumbing", "H12_electric", 
"H12_electric", "H12_electric", "H12_electric"), brand = c("Nitrofill", 
"Antileak", "Nitrofill", "Antileak", "Shock", "Lightning", "Shock", 
"Lightning"), amount = c(6L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: This works, just so I understand what happens:

# this creates the extra column?
df[, favorite := brand[which.max(amount)], by = .(customer, productcategory)] 

# this creates the summarize dataframe?
df[  , dcast(unique(.SD, by = c("customer", "productcategory")), 
          customer ~ productcategory, 
          value.var = "favorite")
]

One additional question: what happens when the amount is the same? If I check this it seems it takes the first one?

Comment: Yes, `favorite := brand[which.max...` creates a new column called "favorite". Note that `which.max` takes the *first* value that is the maximum. So if you have multiples with the same as the maximum value, it would take the first one (first position or index) encountered.

Comment: Yes, the `dcast` creates the summary data.frame, putting the data into wide format.

Comment: @Frank See edited answer - this is a bit simpler, and does not require `unique(.SD...)` in `dcast`. In this case, the data.frame is now summarised and contains the brand with the `max` `amount`, and then `dcast` to put into wide format (no duplicates now with the summarised version).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(dat)
> dcast(dat[ , .(favourite=brand[which.max(amount)]), by=.(customer, productcategory) ], customer ~ productcategory)

   customer H11_plumbing H12_electric
1:      ABC    Nitrofill        Shock
2:      DEF     Antileak    Lightning
```

To break it down:

We can use `data.table` to find the brand corresponding to the maximum amount for each combination of customer and category as follows:

```
> dat[ , .(favourite=brand[which.max(amount)]), by=.(customer, productcategory) ]
   customer productcategory favourite
1:      ABC    H11_plumbing Nitrofill
2:      DEF    H11_plumbing  Antileak
3:      ABC    H12_electric     Shock
4:      DEF    H12_electric Lightning
```

Then use `dcast` to reshape this table with `customer` as the column and `productcategory` along the rows.